# Intercept signal / event when 'Stop Debugging' button is pressed in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, signals

**Background:** I am writing a QA automation platform for an API which outputs formatted results to a specified directory. In addition, I have developed a GUI application for analyzing these results. A user may run the second application trying to analyze test results while our automated build system is running the first application modifying / generating new test data. To avoid thrashing, I have each application acquire file locks when making modifications, and releasing them when they are done. Upon normal program termination, if the running application has acquired a lock on the data directory it is released.

**Problem:** I need to be able to release the aforementioned file locks when either tool exists prematurely (user pressing CTRL-C, user stopping the application in debugger, or due to buggy API / application logic being tested). To handle this, I have implemented a signal handler using [sigaction](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) which handles intercepting fatal signals (tested and working), and have implemented a ctrl-c handler via the Win32 function [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016(v=vs.85).aspx). However, I cannot seem to find a way to intercept the event of a user pressing the ***Stop Debugging*** button in Visual Studio. I assume this event generates something like SIGKILL / SIGSTOP (which cannot be handled through sigaction) but I would also hope there is some std library or Win32 functionality to intercept this event and perform some cleanup. Do you guys know of a way to handle this event or even what exactly this button does to kill a running application?

Comment: The button will call `TerminateProcess`. There is no way for the target process to intercept that. However, a dying process will automatically release all locks (and all handles and all memory). What is not working for you?

Comment: As the file locks are acquired over nfs I cannot use flock. Also I cannot use fnctl as it is not available on windows. I use mkdir / rmdir as described in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228915/proper-way-to-use-lock-files-as-locks-between-multiple-processes

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use F_SETLK/F_UNLCK fcntl locks on non Windows platforms and use some Win32 locking function on windows. Do you know of any Win32 file locking functions that work over nfs?

Comment: Use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're using boost, you can use **[boost::interprocess::windows_shared_memory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/windows_shared_memory.html)**.

It is guaranteed to be released when the process ends.

Boost is just a neat wrapper around the windows API in this case. It wraps the Windows **[Named Shared Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx)** API.